# Sum of a field for all the checked rows with JS

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html

I'm actually doing a website where the user register to an event and order extra activites and i'm stuck with the calculation of the extra's part.
I have a fixed price for the event and a table for all the extra activities.

What I need to do is a function on JS who calculate the price of all the extra activites who are checked in the table.
I already use the value to pass the id of those extra activites (with a push on an array) in my POST ajax so i'm looking for a solution to get the price of all the extra activites who are checked when i'm in the JS function.

I've read some other posts but i can't find something really related to my needs so i'm kinda lost here.

I started the JS function but as you can see i don't know what to put inside.

Should I do a loop?
Is there a way to do it without using values or can i send 2 values?

Any help?

Table :

```
    <div class="shadow-sm p-2 mb-3 rounded">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <h5>Extra activities</h5>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table id="SubEventstables" class="table table-hover table-borderless" style="width:98%;margin-left:1%;">
            <thead class="thead" style="background-color:#5AC5F1;color:white">
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">Name</th>
                    <th class="text-center" scope="row"><img src="/images/euro.png" height="25" width="25" title="€"></th>
                    <th class="text-center" scope="row"><img src="/images/calendar.png" height="25" width="25" title="Start date"></th>
                    <th class="text-center" scope="row"><img src="/images/clock.png" height="25" width="25" title="Start time"></th>
                    <th class="text-center" scope="row"><img src="/images/clock.png" height="25" width="25" title="End time"></th>
                    <th class="text-center" scope="row"><img src="/images/to-do.png" height="25" width="25"></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                    <tr class="shadow rounded">
                        <td>test SEV1</td>
                        <td class="text-center" id="test1">15 €</td>
                        <td class="text-center">12-12-19</td>
                        <td class="text-center">10:00</td>
                        <td class="text-center">12:00</td>
                        <td class="text-center"><input style=" height:17px; width:17px; margin-top:5px; margin-left:22px" type="checkbox" onchange="calcTotal()" name="CheckSub" id="3" value="3|15" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="shadow rounded">
                        <td>test SEV2</td>
                        <td class="text-center" id="test1">20 €</td>
                        <td class="text-center">12-12-19</td>
                        <td class="text-center">14:00</td>
                        <td class="text-center">15:00</td>
                        <td class="text-center"><input style=" height:17px; width:17px; margin-top:5px; margin-left:22px" type="checkbox" onchange="calcTotal()" name="CheckSub" id="4" value="4|20" /></td>
                    </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input class="form-control" id="pricingExtra" />
        </div>
```

JS function:

```
    function calcTotal() {
        $.each($("input[name='CheckSub']:checked"), function () {
         $('#pricingExtra') +=  $('#test1').val();

        });


    }
```

Any help please?

Comment: Can you please post HTML from the browser itself, and not from the code editor?

Comment: @Vladan I just did it :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there is always a space between the price value and the currency symbol then the below solution should work for you.  This method uses unobtrusive javascript (removed the `onchange` from the html) and does not rely on using `id`, however, it does assume the price is in the second `td` cell.

We use `closest()` to get the table row, then use `find()` together with `td:nth-child(2)` selector to get the second `td` (which holds the price).  Then we `split` on the space to get the price value, and finally convert it to `Number`.

```js
// listen for when checkbox is checked
$("input[name='CheckSub']").on('change', function() {
    var sum = 0;
    
    // loop over each checkbox
    $.each($("input[name='CheckSub']:checked"), function () {
       // find the corresponding row for this checkbox 
       var row = $(this).closest('tr');
       // get the text for the price
       var priceText = row.find('td:nth-child(2)').text();
       // convert to number, assuming there is a space between value and currency symbol 
       var price = Number(priceText.split(' ')[0]);
       sum += price;           
    });
    
    console.log('Total: ' + sum);
    $('#pricingExtra').val(sum);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr class="shadow rounded">
        <td>test SEV1</td>
        <td class="text-center" id="test1">15 €</td>
        <td class="text-center">12-12-19</td>
        <td class="text-center">10:00</td>
        <td class="text-center">12:00</td>
        <td class="text-center"><input style=" height:17px; width:17px; margin-top:5px; margin-left:22px" type="checkbox" name="CheckSub" id="3" value="3|15" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="shadow rounded">
        <td>test SEV2</td>
        <td class="text-center" id="test1">20 €</td>
        <td class="text-center">12-12-19</td>
        <td class="text-center">14:00</td>
        <td class="text-center">15:00</td>
        <td class="text-center"><input style=" height:17px; width:17px; margin-top:5px; margin-left:22px" type="checkbox" name="CheckSub" id="4" value="4|20" /></td>
    </tr>

 </table>

 <div class="col-sm-10">
     <input class="form-control" id="pricingExtra" />
 </div>
```

You could easily modify this to use a css class (or `data-` attributes) to target the price instead (eg `<td class="text-center" class="price">15 €</td>`).

Answer (score 1):

I made the following changes because there are some underlying issues:

- In the document, id element should be unique, therefore you can't have twice `id="test1"`, the change I made is to put it as a class name
- Similarly, the checkbox should be an array, since it can have more than one item, therefore the name instead of `"CheckSub"` should be `"CheckSub[]"`
- I have also removed onchange event written through HTML because jQuery covers it already
- Lastly, the output item that you are showing should have a default value of 0 and is of type `"text"`, or even better `"number"`, if appropriate

For the javascript part, the idea is to find the closest element that has the class `"test1"`, take the HTML out of it and parse only integer value, since you need only the number. A note, if you need to have decimal places, you could use `parseFloat()`
The javascript event is triggered whenever the checkbox is clicked, therefore it's triggered even if the checkbox is unchecked. In the case when the checkbox is checked, you add values, otherwise, subtract.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[name='CheckSub[]']").change(function () {
        var euros = $(this).closest('.shadow').find('.test1').html();
        var currentValue = parseInt($('#pricingExtra').val());
        var newValue = this.checked ? currentValue + parseInt(euros) : currentValue - parseInt(euros);
        $('#pricingExtra').val(newValue + ' €')
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="shadow-sm p-2 mb-3 rounded">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <h5>Extra activities</h5>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table id="SubEventstables" class="table table-hover table-borderless" style="width:98%;margin-left:1%;">
            <thead class="thead" style="background-color:#5AC5F1;color:white">
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">Name</th>
                    <th class="text-center" scope="row"><img src="/images/euro.png" height="25" width="25" title="€"></th>
                    <th class="text-center" scope="row"><img src="/images/calendar.png" height="25" width="25" title="Start date"></th>
                    <th class="text-center" scope="row"><img src="/images/clock.png" height="25" width="25" title="Start time"></th>
                    <th class="text-center" scope="row"><img src="/images/clock.png" height="25" width="25" title="End time"></th>
                    <th class="text-center" scope="row"><img src="/images/to-do.png" height="25" width="25"></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                    <tr class="shadow rounded">
                        <td>test SEV1</td>
                        <td class="text-center test1">15 €</td>
                        <td class="text-center">12-12-19</td>
                        <td class="text-center">10:00</td>
                        <td class="text-center">12:00</td>
                        <td class="text-center"><input style=" height:17px; width:17px; margin-top:5px; margin-left:22px" type="checkbox" name="CheckSub[]" id="3" value="3|15" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="shadow rounded">
                        <td>test SEV2</td>
                        <td class="text-center test1">20 €</td>
                        <td class="text-center">12-12-19</td>
                        <td class="text-center">14:00</td>
                        <td class="text-center">15:00</td>
                        <td class="text-center"><input style=" height:17px; width:17px; margin-top:5px; margin-left:22px" type="checkbox" name="CheckSub[]" id="4" value="4|20" /></td>
                    </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="pricingExtra" value=0 />
        </div>
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a lot for all those explainations! Look pretty clear to me now!